# How to export a variable which is updated within a callback function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie to Node.js and while trying some basic code, I hit upon a problem where I need help.
I have a module example2.js which reads the contents of the file and I want to export a variable which will have all the contents of the line file, which I am trying to access from testExport.js

Here are the file contents.

example2.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
var stream = fs.createReadStream('S1.dat', {flags: 'r', encoding: 'utf-8'});
var buf = "";

module.exports.buffer = buf ;

exports.readFile = function f() {
    stream.on('data', function(d) {
        module.exports.buffer+=d.toString();
        console.log( "Inside function " +  module.exports.buffer );
    });

};
```

testExport.js

```
var e2 = require ('./example2.js');
e2.readFile();
console.log ("From external file" + e2.buffer);
```

How should I export it  such that buffer will have the right value in the testExport.js ?

Comment: AFAIK, readFile is async, so ur log wont work. You should pass a call back function to the readFile method in testExport.js.

Comment: @blessenm, can you please give me an example on how to use callback. I have seen it in a few places but I have not been able to implement in correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `fs.readFileSync()` to load the file once:

```
var fs = require('fs')

exports.buffer = fs.readFileSync('S1.dat', { encoding: 'utf8' });
```

Comment: Well this was just a small example to show the problem. I am actually reading the contents, manipulating it and then storing it in another data structure which needs to be exported. So, I am not sure if readFileSync() will work for me. Also, the file that I am going to work with is very huge so I would prefer not to use readFileSync()

Comment: What's the difference if you end up buffering the whole file anyway (you're already doing `module.exports.buffer+=d.toString()` for the entire file)? Either way the whole file is going to be stored in memory. If you are doing some sort of translation chunk by chunk into a non-string/Buffer form (e.g. a js object or a number), then that's something totally different. In that case you'd need to accept a callback in your function and call that once the transformation is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure on what you're trying to do. But here is an example of what I earlier commented.

`readFile.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.read = function f(file, onData, onEnd) {
    var stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {flags: 'r', encoding: 'utf8'});
    stream.on('data', onData);    
    stream.on('end', onEnd);
};
```

`testExport.js`

```
var readFile = require('./readFile');
var buffer = '';
var chunkCount = 0;

readFile.read('data.json', function(chunk) {
    chunkCount++;
    buffer += chunk;
}, function() {
  console.log(buffer);
  console.log('Reading Completed. Chunk Count:' +chunkCount);
});
```

As you can see, readFile just reads a file you specify and streams to the callback you provide. You can do whatever you want with it inside that call back. `onData` can be called multiple times if the file is large. Hence we will only get the complete stream in `onEnd`.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone dowvoted this, looks right to me. +1

Comment: Thats what I thought too. The down voting process needs to force people to comment or something. Thanks for the +1.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Buffer` doesn't have events of its own to notify when it is updated, you want to pass a callback to `readFile`. This is one option.

example2.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
var stream = fs.createReadStream('S1.dat', {flags: 'r', encoding: 'utf-8'});
var buf = "";

module.exports.buffer = buf ;   

exports.readFile = function f(callback) {
    stream.on('data', function(d) {
        module.exports.buffer+=d.toString();
        console.log( "Inside function " +  module.exports.buffer );
        callback(module.exports.buffer);
    });

};
```

testExport.js

```
var e2 = require ('./example2.js');
e2.readFile(function(buffer) {
    console.log ("From external file" + e2.buffer);
});
```